# How to load a website on React native Webview which have authorized certificates

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, webview, ssl-certificate

I am looking to  https url in WebView on React Native. However, it doesn't load.getting error in web view.

```
code :-1202
description:
"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk."
domain:"NSURLErrorDomain"
```

,
same url is working in safari after giving userid and password. how to set this in web view with url. I am using react native with iOS .

Comment: Hey, Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this will resolve your issue, nor am I sure this issue should be resolved in this way, but a brute force solution might be to add the domain to the `NSExceptionDomains` in your `Info.plist`. You can find more info here, [WORKING WITH APPLE’S APP TRANSPORT SECURITY](https://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/)

Comment: thats already I have in info.plist, does not solve issue, issue is how to I add certificate along with userid and password to load url in web view

Comment: You might want to make that more clear in your question.